# Are default argument conversions considered in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, default-arguments

Consider the following code:

```cpp
void foo(int* = 0); // (1)
void foo(int  = 0); // (2)

int main() {
    foo(0); // OK, calls (2)
    foo();  // error, ambiguous overload
}
```

[Both GCC and clang act like this](https://godbolt.org/z/qYePjE8nr), but I'm not convinced that it's correct.

[[expr.call] p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6) merely says:

> If there is no corresponding argument, the default argument for the parameter is used.

This suggests that once a function call is made, `foo` will turn into `foo(0)` and that `0` will have to be converted to `int*` for (1).

Therefore, I believe both function calls should be valid. However, is there wording which contradicts this idea? Are conversions of default arguments considered to be "free" so that they don't contribute to the conversion sequence?

Comment: The default argument for `int*` is not the literal zero but the null pointer of type `int*`. (It's not a simple text replacement.)

Comment: This behavior looks correct to me.  Overload resolution only considers the conversions for arguments passed to the function: Define 
ICS
i
(
F
)
 as the implicit conversion sequence that converts the 
i
th
 argument in the list to the type of the 
i
th
 parameter of viable function F  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#general-1

Comment: Your quote from the standard follows "when a function is called..." Your error however is telling you that a function is **not** being called, due to ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we can consider something a "function call", the *postfix-expression* (the identifier before `()`) must be resolved from possible overloads (if it's a function name and not e.g. an object). See Note 1 in [[expr.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6):

> [Note 1: If the postfix expression is a function or member function name, the appropriate function and the validity of the call are determined according to the rules in `[over.match]`.
> — end note]

And when doing overload resolution, we have the following  in [[over.match.viable]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#2.3) (emphasis mine):

> First, to be a viable function, a candidate function shall have enough
> parameters to agree in number with the arguments in the list.
>
> (2.1) If there are `m` arguments in the list, all candidate functions having exactly `m` parameters are viable.
> [...]
> (2.3)
> A candidate function having more than `m` parameters is viable only if all parameters following the `m`th have default arguments
> (`[dcl.fct.default]`).
> **For the purposes of overload resolution, the parameter list is truncated on the right, so that there are exactly `m` parameters.**

Your function call has 0 arguments, and both overloads of `foo` have 1 default parameter. This falls into 2.3 - the default parameters are truncated from the parameters lists of both candidate functions, and so we end up with 2 viable functions, both with 0 parameters, indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: This could also be explained through https://eel.is/c++draft/over.call.func#3 (The argument list submitted to overload resolution doesn't include default arguments).